# Modular expression and my trying.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is it a true:?

$$\begin{cases} 2x \equiv 2 \mod 5 \\ 3x \equiv 2 \mod 4 \\5x \equiv 2 \mod 6\end{cases}$$

$$2x \equiv 2 \mod 5  \iff x \equiv 1 \mod 5 $$
$$3x \equiv 2 \mod 4  \iff 6x \equiv 4 \mod 4 \iff 3x \equiv 2 \mod 2 \iff x\equiv 0 \mod 2   $$ 
$$5x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \iff 10x \equiv 4 \mod 6 \iff 5x \equiv 2 \mod 3  \iff
x \equiv 1 \mod 3
$$
So we have got simple system:
$$\begin{cases} x \equiv 1 \mod 5 \\ x \equiv 0 \mod 2 \\x \equiv 1 \mod 3\end{cases}$$
And now we can use CRT.

Comment: Your second two derived congruences are incorrect.

Comment: I edited, and now?

Comment: $3x\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ can't be multiplied through by $2$, similarly for the third congruence.  These operations (multiplying by something not relatively prime to the modulus) does not preserve solutions.

Comment: Well, we *can* multiply a congruence mod $4$ by two, but the logical connective would be $\Rightarrow$ instead of $\Leftrightarrow$ since multiplication by two is not a reversible operation when working mod $4$, and this multiplying by two can introduce extraneous solutions.

Comment: ok, and when it comes to:
$da \equiv db \mod dc \iff a \equiv b \mod c $ Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $3\equiv-1\pmod4,3x\equiv2\pmod4\iff-x\equiv2\iff x\equiv-2$

But $-2\equiv2\pmod4\implies x\equiv2\pmod4\  \ \ \ (1)$

$(1)\implies x\equiv0\pmod2$

Similarly, $5x\equiv2\pmod6\iff-x\equiv2\iff x\equiv-2\iff x\equiv4\pmod6\  \ \ \ (2) $

$(2)\implies x\equiv4\pmod3\equiv1\  \ \ \ (3)$

and $x\equiv4\pmod2\equiv0$

Like [I can't use Chinese Remainder Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098668/chinese-remainder-theorem/1098679#1098679),
$2x\equiv2\pmod5\iff x\equiv1\pmod5\  \ \ \ (4)$

We need CRT on $(1),(3),(4)$

Comment: I know it. I'am asking for to tell me what I do incorrectly.

Comment: @user180834, It's wrong to say $a\equiv b\pmod m\iff a\cdot n\equiv b\cdot n\pmod m,$ but we can say $a\equiv b\pmod m\implies a\cdot n\equiv b\cdot n\pmod m,$

Comment: thanks. very much :)
ok, and when it comes to: $da \equiv bd \mod dc⟺a \equiv b \mod c$  Is it correct? And, it preserver solution?

Comment: @user180834, $da\equiv db\pmod{dc}\iff da=db+k(dc)$ where $k$ is an integer $\iff a=b+k(c)\iff\cdots$